# How to center image on table cell pdf file in iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I can't center on table cell the image using **iTextSharp**.

I have tried in this mode, without success.

The image is always misaligned with respect to the cell and covers the upper cell in the pdf file.

[image]

How to do resolve this?

My code below.

```
string imagePath = "~/aspnet/Img/pdf.gif";
iTextSharp.text.Image image2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
image2.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
Chunk cImage = new Chunk(image2, 0, 0, false);
Anchor anchor = new Anchor(cImage);
anchor.Reference = "www.mywebsite.com";
table.AddCell(anchor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this.

You must use the property [Annotation of iTextSharp](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/clone-creating-and-adding-annotations).

```
string imagePath = "~/aspnet/Img/pdf.gif";
iTextSharp.text.Image image2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(image2);
cell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
cell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
cell2.FixedHeight = 20;
image2.Annotation = new Annotation(0, 0, 0, 0, "www.mywebsite.com");
table.AddCell(cell2);
```